# Is it possible for a bot to have a dynamic name in Slack?

Tags: bots, slack-api

Is it possible to create a bot in slack which has a dynamic name, or who posts under a different name depending on a given situation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is an example in perl, which uses the hostname and pid to generate the name of the bot.

```
sub slack {
  my ( $message ) = @_;

  use LWP::UserAgent;
  use HTTP::Request;
  use Sys::Hostname;

  my $uri = "https://hooks.slack.com/services/"
    . "this-is-your-api-key";

  my $json = '{"channel": "#example_channel", '
    . '"username": "' . hostname . "." . $$ . '", '
    . '"text": "' . $message . '", '
    . '"icon_emoji": ":trollface:"}' ;

  my $request = HTTP::Request->new( 'POST', $uri );
  $request->header( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
  $request->content( $json );

  my $agent = LWP::UserAgent->new;

  my $result = $agent->request( $request );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When sending a message via incoming webhook, you have the option of sending a parameter `username` which specifies the name that will appear i.e.

```
{
    "text": "the message i'm sending",
    "username": "whatever-name-you-want"
}
```

(You can also specify a different icon on every message using the `icon_url` parameter with a value of a URL to the image you want)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#sending_messages_as_other_entities

Javascript example:

```
    await client.chat.postMessage({
        channel: "C12345",
        text: "Random message",
        username: "John Doe",
        icon_url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/12/Profile_avatar_generic.png"
    });
```

A fuller implementation could look something like:

```
const triggerRegExp = new RegExp('^(Hello).*', 'i');

app.message(triggerRegExp, async (payload) => {
    ({ message, client } = payload);

    await client.chat.postMessage({
        channel: message.channel,
        text: "Random message",
        username: "John Doe",
        icon_url: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/12/Profile_avatar_generic.png"
    });
});
```